# How Azure Stream Analytics find schema of data coming from Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am following this tutorial to understand how `Stream Analytics` work on `Azure`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-real-time-fraud-detection?toc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json

A `cmd` event generator application is sending data to `event hub` to which a `stream analytics` job is connected. I don't understand two things

1. I have not specified data schema anywhere, yet I can query the data. How?
2. The tuturial recommends that I create a consumer group in event hub. A consumer group `MyConsumerGroup` is created in the tutorial but never used. What is the purpose of the consumer group?

Comment: anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sourcecode of the generator at `https://github.com/Azure/azure-stream-analytics/blob/master/DataGenerators/TelcoGenerator/Program.cs`, it seems the data is sent in `json` and internally `Analytics Stream Service` is able to detect the structure of the `json`.

```
var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
```

Just guessing.